# How to use ternary operator(?:) or Null Coalescing operator(??) to write if-else condition?

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
if(country1 != null)
{ 
    country1 = "Turkey";
}
else
{
country1 = "ABD";
}
```

Comment: Can you add a detailed question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ternary operators use three operands:

A condition followed by a `?`, 
followed by an expression to evaluate if the condition is 'truthy', followed by a `:`, 
followed by an expression to evaluate if the condition is `falsey`.

So in your case, what you'd want to do is this:

```
country1 = country1 != null ? 'Turkey' : 'ABD';
```

EDIT:

You seem a little confused about `??` operator. `??` is called **Null Coalescing operator**

```
x = x ?? 'foo';
```

is equivalent to

```
if( x == null )
    x = 'foo';
else
    x = *whatever the value previously was*;
```

so if we have `x` set to `bar` before the check, it won't change to `foo` because `bar` is not equal to `null`. Also, note that the `else` statement here is redundant.

*so `??` will set the variable to some value only if it was previously null*.

In your code, you are trying to assign one of the two values `Turkey` or `ABD`, and not a single value if the previous value was null. So you get a syntax error.

So, to summarize.

```
if() {}
else {}
```

can be shortened using the ternary operator `? :`.

and

```
if(){}
```

can be shortened using the `??` operator, because the else statement here will simply be redundant.

Thus, the equivalent of your code won't use `??` operator.

Comment: Hello, Thanks first of all! I got confused about null. Normally, we can use double questions with the ternary operator. ?? is a null check operator.
Ex: String Country = country1  ?? " ABD" so I want to use double questions instead null check.

country1 = country1 != ?? 'Turkey' : 'ABD'; (the code giving error ) 
What can I do?

Comment: I got it! Thanks  Doc

Answer (score 2):

```
var s = country1 != null ? "Turkey" : "ABD";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final result = country1 != null ? 'Turkey' : 'ABD';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax:**
var result = a != null ? condition is true then further code :  condition is false then further code;

**in your case :**
var result = country1 != null ? "Turkey" : "ABD";

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way too:

```
final result = "${country1 != null ? 'Turkey' : 'ABD'}";
```