# How to use short if in flutter?

Tags: flutter, if-statement, dart

How to use short if in flutter

this code can use:

```
1 + 1 == 2 ? print('check true') : print('check false');
Ans. print('check true')
```

but I want to do this:

```
1 + 1 == 2 ?? print('check true');
```

Why code can't print check true?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910273/how-to-use-ternary-operator-or-null-coalescing-operator-to-write-if-else

Comment: The ?? is called null aware and checks if 1+1==2 is null. If the expression on the left of ?? evaluates to null then the print statement is executed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply

```
1 + 1 == 2 ? print('check true') : print('check false');
```

is equals to

```
if(1+1 == 2) {
    print('check true');
else {
    print('check false');
}
```

and

```
1 + 1 == 2 ?? print('check true');
```

is equals to

```
if((1+1 == 2) == null ) {
    print('check true');
}
```

Comment: just tried `1 + 1 == 2 ?? print('check true');`. This does not work. `??` provides a default value in case the expression to the left is null

Answer (score 1):

The short form always require an else statement. And as said in the comments, ?? provides a default value if an object is null. With widgets, you could for example always write `a == b ? c() : Container()` because you cannot see `Container()` without a size

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, I think is shorter and easy understand: `if (1+1 == 2) print('check true');`