# Initialize with flexible keys in fromJson

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I want to set Movie/TV information values that fetch form API, but what some JSON keys are different, but values types are same the difference is not so much to create another model for that, so I want to continue with main `model` class.

For example `title` is key for **movie** but for **TV** is `name` key in JSON, and some other keys that are different.

I've tried to solve it with checking, but it did not work:

```
 final String? title;
 factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Result(
        title: json["title"] == Null ? json["name"] : json["title"],
...
)
```

As I mentioned that work for **Movie** but for **TV** will not work, error that shows for that:

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

I also tried this method, but it didn't work for both parts as before:

```
 title: json["name"] ?? json["title"]
```

How can I handle initialization with flexible keys?

Comment: I think the keyword is `null` (case sensitive)

Comment: let's try with this `json["title"] == null ? json["name"] : json["title"],`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Null` is not string type, you can check with `null`

```
json["title"] == null ? json["name"] : json["title"],
```

Comment: It worked, but what's the difference between this and `??` ?

Comment: basically, there is no difference between. But you checked different conditions in two statements. For more http://blog.sethladd.com/2015/07/null-aware-operators-in-dart.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910273/how-to-use-ternary-operator-or-null-coalescing-operator-to-write-if-else

Comment: is It work for you please mark it as an answer.